# Pyspark: dynamically generate condition for when() clause during runtime

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have read a csv file into `pyspark dataframe`. 
Now if I apply conditions in `when()` clause, it works fine when the conditions are given before `runtime`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

sc = SparkContext('local', 'example')
sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)

pandas_df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')  # assuming the file contains a header
# Sample content of csv file
# col1,value
# 1,aa
# 2,bbb

s_df = sql_sc.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

new_df = s_df.withColumn('value', functions.when((col("col1") == 2) | (col("value") == "aa"), s_df.value).otherwise(
    2))

new_df.show(truncate=False)
```

But I need to dynamically form the conditions inside when clause from a list.

```
[{'column': 'col1', 'operator': '==', 'value': 2}, {'column': 'value', 'operator': '==', 'value': "aa"}]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. dynamically generate the SQL string, Python 3.6+' f-strings are really convenient for this.
2. pass it to the `pyspark.sql.functions.expr` to make a `pyspark.sql.column.Column` out of it.

---

For your example, something like this should work:

Given `s_df` 's schema:

```
root
 |-- col1: long (nullable = false)
 |-- value: string (nullable = false)
```

Importing functions and instantiate your conditions collection:

```py
[...]
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, when
conditions = [
    {'column': 'col1', 'operator': '==', 'value':  3}, 
    {'column': 'value', 'operator': '==', 'value': "'aa'"}
]
```

- With generation of the entire if statement:

```py
new_df = s_df.withColumn('value', expr(
    f"IF({conditions[0]['column']}{conditions[0]['operator']}{conditions[0]['value']}"
    f" OR {conditions[1]['column']}{conditions[1]['operator']}{conditions[1]['value']},"
    "value, 2)")).show()
```

- Or with only the generation of the condition, passed to the `when` function.

```py
new_df = s_df.withColumn('value',when(
    expr(
        f"{conditions[0]['column']}{conditions[0]['operator']}{conditions[0]['value']}"
        f" OR {conditions[1]['column']}{conditions[1]['operator']}{conditions[1]['value']}"
    ),
    col("value")).otherwise(2)).show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a sample SQL string inside when clause for the above values?

Comment: ``new_df = s_df.withColumn('value', functions.expr("if(col('col1') == 2 OR col('value') == 'aa'"), col('value'), 2)``

.
I tried the above statement with hardcoded condition. But this throws error
saying, 
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: "\nmismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 43)\n\n== SQL ==\nif(col('col1') == 2 OR col('value') == 'aa'\n-------------------------------------------^^^\n"
<br/>
``new_df = s_df.withColumn('value', functions.expr("if(col1 == 2 OR value == 'aa'"), value, 2)`` is also not working

Comment: I edited with an example using f-strings (python 3.6+), make sure you put additional quotes for strings in the conditions' values: `"'aa'"` not just `"aa"`.

Comment: The detailed answer really helped.