# Pyspark: dynamically generate condition for when() clause with variable number of columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a function to which I am passing a dataframe and listofcolumns which should not contain a NULL value. If any of the columns from "listofcolumns" has a null value, I need to take an action.

Now, I have to use the when clause here but the columns passed to the when clause will vary based on the dataframe and listofcolumns passed.  So I want to be able to generate the when clause dynamically using the columns passed. The when clause could be checking for NULL value in just one column or multiple columns in the dataframe. Thus I cannot hard code to use one condition or multiple conditions.

I have tried generating the whenClause string dynamically and passing as a variable but get an error that "TypeError: condition should be a Column".

Can someone please advise how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with resolving your the selection logic on your columns ahead of time and then using `functools.reduce` and `operator`, such as:

```
import functools
import operator

import pyspark.sql.functions as f


# conditional selection of columns - your logic on selecting 
# which columns to check for null goes here
my_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "condition" in col]

# now I want to create my condition on these columns
# since it can be any of them, I use operator.or_
# but your logic may vary here - apply to my_cols created above
cond_expr = functools.reduce(operator.or_, [f.col(c).isNull() for c in my_cols])

# now you apply your action
df.withColumn(
  "output_column",
  f.when(cond_expr, TRUE_ACTION).otherwise(FALSE_ACTION)
)
```

Where `TRUE_ACTION` is when your condition of any equal to `null` is satisfied. If you wish to check for all columns in your condition being null, replace `operator.or_` with `operator.and_` and build your logic from there. Hope this helps!

Comment: Very neat, +1. In terms of performance, is this as efficient as using `expr()` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763170/1214974)? And how about in comparison to "hardcoding" the long OR expression in the `when` call (as in `when(col('a') == 'x' | col('b') == 'y' | ..., ...)`)? I'm new to pyspark and it's not clear to me if any/all of these approaches result in a UDF, which could hurt performance. Thank you!